# Flexibly naming tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake client)

.........................

I would like to flexibly name tables I create.

For example

```
Set name = April
```

and then

```
Create table customer_data_$name as
```

I've found two recommended options thus far:

## 1 - Using Snowsql:

```
snowsql -c myconn -w trainingwh --variable NAME=April -f test.sql  -o variable_substitution=True
```

script test.sql:

```
create table mytab_&NAME as
select current_timestamp ts;
```

## 2 - Using JavaScript Stored procedures:

```
create or replace procedure Proc_CT(NAME varchar)
RETURNS varchar(22)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
Execute as OWNER
as
$$
  var ct_qry = `create or replace table mytab_`+NAME+`(i int);`
  var ct_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: ct_qry });
  ct_stmt.execute();
    return 'Done.';
$$
;

CALL Proc_CT('April');
```

**Two Questions:**

A. Out of these two recommendations, is there any reason to leverage one more than the other?

B. Are there any other recommended options that can be leveraged in this situation?

.........................

Any advice or additional recommendations would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Of the 2 options, I'd go with the stored procedure over Snowsql, because it's a more portable solution.  Snowsql needs to be executed from a host machine, while stored procedures can be executed from anywhere, since they run inside Snowflake.  This way, if you want to do this within an ELT/ETL process using a third-party tool, python, java, etc., you could simply call the SP to create your table.

As a note, I'd probably create a SP that renames a table for me, rather than doing the full CTAS statement.  Your process could then create a table without an SP being involved, and then you could pass the table name + $name values into the SP and have it rename it for you.  Either way works, but that's how I'd do it.